# Does Google Chrome collect data unrelated to browsing activity?

Tags: google, software

I'm exclusively running Firefox, but I'd like to install the leading browser Chrome for troubleshooting purposes. Browsing-related data collection isn't a concern in this case, but I'm worried if the browser logs key input on the background or scans and uploads files or related data to their server without notifying the user.

Comment: It seems like you are asking if it illegally and without the user's knowledge collects data that it does not disclose. If they did that, 1) we would not know, or 2) it would be well-known, or 3) Chrome would be shunned as a browser.

Comment: Google: Yes we do regardless what are privacy policy says which we intentionally made lengthy and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an "on-demand" virus capability provided by ESET.  This also does a periodic scan of all your files.  If it detects "malware" it will send meta-data of that file back to Google.

https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/wj7x9w/google-chrome-scans-files-on-your-windows-computer-chrome-cleanup-tool

Chrome also can log keystrokes for the purpose of "spelling error correction"  but I believe this is in opt-in feature.

For a full list of what data chrome collects (at least according to Google) check out their white paper.

https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html